# npm install composer-cli error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am getting below error when to deploy the busniess network.

composer network deploy

It work with above command. We need to install npm install composer-cli first.

I tried to install that command i am getting the below error

2 info using npm@6.0.1
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /home/XXX/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose npm-session 7500b569e0b5ec68
6 verbose stack TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not object
6 verbose stack     at Url.parse (url.js:103:11)
6 verbose stack     at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:97:13)
6 verbose stack     at fixupUnqualifiedGist (/home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/hosted-git-info/index.js:94:20)
6 verbose stack     at fromUrl (/home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/hosted-git-info/index.js:40:13)
6 verbose stack     at Function.module.exports.fromUrl (/home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/hosted-git-info/index.js:32:18)
6 verbose stack     at Function.resolve (/home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:69:28)
6 verbose stack     at Object.keys.forEach.name (/home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lock-verify/index.js:26:26)
6 verbose stack     at Array.forEach ()
6 verbose stack     at Promise.all.then.result (/home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lock-verify/index.js:25:25)
6 verbose stack     at 
7 verbose cwd /home/ragesh
8 verbose Linux 4.15.0-23-generic
9 verbose argv "/home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/bin/node" "/home/XXX/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/bin/npm" "audit"
10 verbose node v8.11.2
11 verbose npm  v6.0.1
12 error Parameter "url" must be a string, not object
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Can you please guide me..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

For Composer v0.19.8 (the latest version) you should have node v8.9 or later so your version 8.11 should be fine.

You should install composer with this command `npm install -g composer-cli`

For composer v0.19 the command `composer network deploy` has been removed, and you will now need `composer network install` and `composer network start`

Note also that Composer v0.19 required Fabric v1.1.0.

[These instructions](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html) should help.